# Delete old elasticsearch logs from a specific type

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, logstash, nest

I am using elasticsearch to store logs from more than one system.
I seperate the logs from different systems by using a different _type name for each system log.
I am trying to write an old-logs-deleter which will delete logs that are older than some date...
When I use Nest to do this, It seems that I delete all the types and not only the one i specified.

```
var client = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"),"someindex");
client.deleteByQuery(new DeleteByQueryRequest
{
   AllIndices = true,
   AllType = true,
   Q = "_type:someType",
   Query = new QueryContainer(new RangeQuery
   {
       Field = new PropertyPathMarker
       {
           Name = "@timestamp"
       },
       LowerThan = dateToSaveFrom.ToString("O")
   })
}
```

I tried so many times with different variations and it just doesn't work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`Q` and `Query` are mutually exclusive here, and `Query` is taking precedence.

Since you're explicitly setting `AllTypes = true`, and specifying both `Q` and `Query`, `Q` is ignored and the `RangeQuery` is running across all your types.

Instead, just drop `Q` and use `Types` to specify only the type(s) you wish to delete.

```
new DeleteByQueryRequest
{
   AllIndices = true,
   Types = new TypeNameMarker [] { "someType" },
   Query = new QueryContainer(new RangeQuery
   {
       Field = new PropertyPathMarker
       {
           Name = "@timestamp"
       },
       LowerThan = dateToSaveFrom.ToString("O")
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly using curl as below.

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/_query' -d '{
    "match_all" : {}
}'
```

Here by pointing to the index and type , you can remove the type.